# PHP: Implode Comma Separated in min() function

Tags: php, mysql, implode

I'm trying to implement the `min()` function in my PHP code. The min value should be retried like this:

```
$ar=array($data[Price]);
echo min($ar);
```

The problem is that when I echo out `$data[Price]` I get my prices without commas nor spaces, so it becomes something like this:

```
$ar=array($data[Price]);
echo min(373945);
```

But it should be:

```
echo min(37, 39, 45);
```

to get 37.

Is there any way to get comma separated values with `implode`?

My `var_dump` result of `$data[Price]`:

```
NULL 37.00NULL 39.00NULL 45.00
```

Comment: Can you add a `var_dump($data[Price])`, so we can see what the actual data you're working with is?

Comment: Then first its `$data[Price]` which needs to be formatted accordingly, Rest of the things will resolve auto

Comment: is `Price` a constant?

Comment: Price is a Column in myTable

Comment: @user2635574 - you don't need the `array`, I think. Just pass `$data['Price']` into `min()` as it is.

Comment: @andrewsi  37.0039.0045.00

Comment: If you want "Is there any way to get comma separated values with implode?" answer, check below.

Comment: @user2635574 - put `var_dump($data['Price'])` on the line before you call `min()`. What is the output?

Comment: string(5) "34.00" 34.00string(5) "37.00" 37.00  this if my query gets 2 results. I also use while (loop)!

Comment: Your `var_dump` isn't a `var_dump`. `E_MISSING_INFORMATION`

Comment: @user2635574 - so. You're running this code in a loop? That should have been in your initial question.

Comment: If you only want the lowest price why dont you just fetch the lowest price from your database in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a short sample:

```
$array = array('lastname', 'email', 'phone');
foreach($array as &$value){
   $value = "'$value'";
}
$comma_separated = implode(",", $array);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what `$data[Price]` contains. If this is the value you get using var_dump, as you say:

```
NULL 37.00NULL 39.00NULL 45.00
```

You could do this:

```
$price = explode('NULL ', $data[Price]);
echo min($price);
```